# Criar um cadastro em que o usuário incrementa um novo checkbox para ser salvo uma nova informação no MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Preciso criar um cadastro de clientes, onde determinada parte do cadastramento o usuário tem vários checkbox que utilizaria para armazenar se o cliente possui tais documentos, por exemplo:

```
[] RG 
[X] CPF
[] Certidão de nascimento
```

e um botão para que possa "Adicionar novo elemento" que não esteja na lista, onde cada vez que clica ele cria um novo checkbox com a descrição que o usuário desejar e poderá marca-lo para ser salvo em uma tabela mysql.

Como posso fazer isso? ou como posso pesquisar algo na internet que tenha esse código parecido?

Answer (score -1):

Encontrei um código na net que me deu uma luz..
Não implementei ainda mas é basicamente isso:

> JavaScript:

At First include the jQuery library.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See the below JavaScript comment lines. maxField variable holding the maximum fields increment numbers, addButton variable holding the input fields adding button class, wrapper variable holding all input fields parent div class, fieldHTML variable holding new input field HTML code.

Once the “Add button” is clicked, we will check maximum input fields number. If field counter (x) is less than maxField, the new input field HTML would be append into the fields parent div (wrapper). Also the field counter would be incremented.

Once the “Remove button” is clicked, the parent div of that particular remove button would be removed. Also the field counter would be decrement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
</script>
```

> HTML:

```
<div class="field_wrapper">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

> PHP:

Once the multiple form fields are submitted, then you can get the values as an array in PHP script.

```
  <?php
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($_REQUEST['field_name']);
    print '</pre>';
    //output
    Array
    (
        [0] => value1
        [1] => value2
        [2] => value3
        [3] => value4
    )
    ?>
```

Now you can run a foreach loop and insert the values into the database or whatever you want.

```
  <?php
    $field_values_array = $_REQUEST['field_name'];
    foreach($field_values_array as $value){
        //your database query goes here
    }
    ?>
```

Fonte: http://www.codexworld.com/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-using-jquery/

Comment: se vc nao tem uma resposta melhor entao nao tem pq negativar o post

Answer (score -2):

Bom cara isso se chama: Criação de componentes em tempo de execução. Bom cara no php é mais fácil você fazer isso usando a função echo do php.
Exemplo:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">';
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta.

Comment: Mas como não? Eu dei o exemplo de como cria o componente em tempo de execução agora ele irá adaptar no código dele, porque eu não tenho o código que ele está fazendo para colocar completamente, sendo assim eu dei o exemplo de como se criar o elemento em tempo de execução para ele adaptar, ué. O cara nem deu o código que está tentando, então dei um exemplo de como fazer. Acho que o povo aqui tá sendo ignorante demais.

Comment: Oque tenho observado é que aqui tem muitos perfeccionistas de modismo, porque oque eu vejo acontecer é meia duzia de caras que copiam conteúdo de outros website para responder a pergunta aqui e coloca um texto de 200 linhas e todo mundo dá positivo(muitos nem leêm), Agora se você dá um resposta simples porem eficiente sempre tem um #$#$#$#@ para dar negativo, E falo mais... Quem tem que dar negativo é o rapaz que está perguntando ele sim verá se a resposta ajuda ou não, pior que o povo se mete e muitas vezes nem ajuda em nada.

Comment: Jovem, eu só disse que a sua resposta não responde à pergunta. Ela, talvez, possa levar o OP até o caminho correto, mas de longe não é uma resposta que resolva o problema. Se você se ofender com toda negativada que tomar por aqui, essa talvez não seja a melhor comunidade pra você.